# can you help me? ubuntu 20.04 sometimes not accepting any keyboard input

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, firefox, libreoffice

The problem occurs when I'm encoding something in Libreoffice Calc, Oracle, and Mozilla firefox. This has happened to me twice this week, and the problem resolves when I click on settings; the keyboard accepts input again.

I already tried disabling hardware acceleration of LibreOffice and Mozilla Firefox. Do you have any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.